# Characterizing a "like" normal matrix

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Can we characterize the set of all $n\times n$ invertible matrices $H(z)$ with entire functions entries such that  $H(z)H^{\#}(z)=H^{\#}(z)H(z)$, and $\det(H(z))\neq 0, \forall z\in \mathbb{C}$, where $H^{\#}(z)=\left(\overline{H(\bar{z})} \right)^{T}=H^{*}(\bar{z})$?

(Note: Few months ago Robert Israel solved a similar problem for normal matrices, $HH^{*}=H^{*}H$ [[Link]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3422905/normal-complex-matrix-valued-function). But I think the case here is more general!)

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in how to talk about kinds of non-normal cases, then you might benefit from looking at ways that authors have characterized "how" non-normal a matrix is.  In that case, I can recommend the piece in Trefethen and Embree's *Spectra and Pseudospectra* called "Scalar measures of non-normality".

Briefly, some simple examples are: the condition number for the matrix of eigenvectors (non-diagonalizable matrices = $\infty$ in that case) and the perturbative distance from a normal matrix (which has no closed-form solution so far).

I do not know enough about your specific problem to say how helpful these sources will be, but it is a start.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think there are some obvious examples of such $H(z)$ where it is non-diagonalizable?

Comment: I've not thought very much about your issue, wouldn't a case where all the entries are constants work?  E.g. H(z) = [0 1; 0 0]

Comment: But $H$ is supposed to be invertible!

Comment: Well then H(z) = [1 1; 0 1]

Comment: I think constant matrices examples will satisfy $H^{*} =H^{\#} $, so nothing new here.

Comment: Like I said, I'm not trying to solve your general issue, only answer your questions.

Comment: Thank you for your interest.